# Why do I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error when using Sortable package in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I've encountered a problem with the Kyslik\Column-sortable package for Laravel which has frustrated me for weeks now. :)
The sorting links displays correctly, but when I click on one of the sorting links, I get the following error:
 Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\GeekCollector\resources\views\Lp\show.blade.php)
What's even more strange is that the route goes to the BrowseResults view, but the message sais that the error was encountered in the Show view.
If I remove all the sortable related stuff from the BrowseResults view, the Show view works perfectly.
Here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;
class Lp extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Sortable;
    public $sortable = ['title', 'artist', 'year'];
}
```

Here is my BrowseResults controller method:

```
public function browseResults(Request $request)
    {
        $chosenCategory = $request->category;
$lps = Lp::where('category','like','%'.$chosenCategory.'%');
$result = $lps->sortable('title')->paginate(5);


    return view('Lp.browseResults', compact('result'));
    
    }
```

And here is my blade view:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h1 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            Lp-skivor
        </h1>
    </x-slot>
@sortablelink('title')
@sortablelink('artist')
@sortablelink('year')
<table>
<tr>
<td>Titel</td>
<td>Artist</td>
<td>Kategori</td>
<td>Plats</td>
<td>Position</td>
</tr>
@foreach ($result as $lp)
<tr>
<td>
<a href="{{ route('lp.show', $lp->id) }}">{{ $lp->title }}</a>
</td>
<td>{{ $lp->artist }}</td>
<td> {{ $lp->category }}</td>
<td>{{ $lp->place }}</td>
<td>{{ $lp->position }}</td>
<td>
<a href="{{ route('lp.edit', $lp->id) }}">Uppdatera</a>
</td>
<td>
<form action="{{ route('lp.destroy', $lp->id) }}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')

                    <button type="submit">Ta bort</button>
                
                </form>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
{!! $result->appends(\Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
</x-app-layout>
```

The route looks like this:

```
Route::post('/lp/browse-results', [LpController::class, 'browseResults'])->name('lp.browseResults');
```

Thanks very much in advance for your help!

All the best!

Comment: Have you tried using `php artisan cache:clear`,  `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan route:clear` ? It sounds like you either are not executing the function you think you are executing, or its loading an older version via cache.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried all three commands but unfortunately the same error appears again. :(